# Torque2D default t2dTileMap object

Tags: scripting, torque

When I start a blank project I have noticed that I get one `t2dSceneGraph` and one `t2dTileMap` (under the project tab). I selected the `t2dTileMap` and gave it a name '*tilemap*'.

In my `game.cs` function `startGame` I added

```
%LayerCount = tilemap.getTileLayerCount();
```

...but when I execute the project and inspect the variable `%LayerCount` in Torsion I first of all get an error:

```
Unable to find object: 'tilemap' attempting to call function 'getTileLayerCount'
```

How do I access the default `t2dTileMap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind here is the answer if somone else would like to know...

```
%tileMap = $LastLoadedScene.getGlobalTileMap();  
%layerCount = %tilemap.getTileLayerCount();
```